# When js references a module, it uses a module under TypeScript, but I want to use node_modules

Tags: typescript, import

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNktB.png)

[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhFCP.png)

When I installed React in node_modules. Reacting in Rex in index.js is beyond my expectation. It refers to React in TypeScipt.
Can someone tell me what is the reason?